# Which NDS emulator run better in Ubuntu?

Tags: emulation

I just want to know, which nds emulator run better(performance) in Ubuntu 11.04?

it doesn't matter if it run on wine or natively.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Desmume is the best on Ubuntu and it's in the Ubuntu Software Center.

Comment: You'll have better performance if you run No$GBA. It's only for Windows, but you can run perfectly on Wine. For slow processors, such as the first Dual Core processors or below, No$GBA is much faster than Desmume.